# Linq - get objects with a list property that does not contain values in another list

Tags: c#, linq

I feel like a complete idiot not being able to work this out myself.

I have a list of "Booking" objects called ExistingBookings. I also have an ObservableCollection of "Count" objects each of which has a "Bookings" property which is a list of "Booking" objects.

Using Linq, how do I select all the Count objects whose "Bookings" property does not contain any of the "Booking" objects in ExistingBookings?

i.e.

```
List<Booking> ExistingBookings = new List<Booking>();
ExistingBookings.Add(Booking1);
ExistingBookings.Add(Booking2);

Count1 = new Count();
Count1.Bookings.Add(Booking2);
Count1.Bookings.Add(Booking3);

Count2 = new Count();
Count1.Bookings.Add(Booking3);
Count1.Bookings.Add(Booking4);

List<Count> counts = new List<Count>();
counts.Add(Count1);
counts.Add(Count2);
```

I am expecting the output to be a list of Count objects containing only Count2, since neither of its Booking objects exist in ExistingBookings.

Please put me out of my misery :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `Booking` class implements equality and hash codes correctly you can use:

```
var result = counts.Where(c => !c.Bookings.Intersect(ExistingBookings).Any());
```

Comment: Thank you. I had in fact done something very similar to this but using Count() == 0 ather than Any() at the end. Having just rebuilt and restarted the solution, both seem to work so it must have been some weird debugging thing that was stopping me doing this. Thanks for confirming I'm not quite as dumb as I thought.

Answer (score 1):

```
counts.Where(c => c.Bookings.All(b => !ExistingBookings.Contains(b)));
```